# Positioning div off-screen to the right using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Strictly using JavaScript, I'd like to position the following div element *right* outside the window, to the right, so that no horizontal scrollbar is present.

How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<div id = "content">
    <header>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
    </header>
</div>
```

I was thinking something like

```
$( "#content" ).offset({ left: 1345});
```

but that unfortunately results in a scrollbar, **and** it isn't responsive, causing the div to be located far outside the right edge of the window when in mobile view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the `window.innerWidth;` value and set that as the left position value it'll hang out right outside of the viewports width.

You'd need to set either your wrapper or body to `overflow: hidden;` to get rid of the horizontal scroll though.

```
var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('content');
var docWidth = window.innerWidth;

hiddenDiv.style.position = 'relative'; // Or absolute, depending on what you want
hiddenDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
hiddenDiv.style.left = docWidth+'px';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c62sqvdk/ <-- JsFiddle for visual example.

Comment: Hey, I got a question. Your code is perfect. However, before I put your code to use, I have a function that animates the div/slides it offscreen to the left like so: $('#content').animate({ 'margin-left' : "-25%" },2000, function() {} and the problem is that this causes the content to which your code pertains (a new, loaded div) to be located "25%" *inside* the window due to the margin-left business. Is there a way to fix this - if you know what I mean?

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand. The div on page load is located where exactly? If you have two divs or sections with the same ID that's another problem. IDs are meant to be unique. This would be the perfect example of why that's the case. If I'm misunderstanding let me know maybe I can further assist you. Posting your code in a fiddle or pen would help a bit as well. :)

Comment: No problem. It's all sorted out now.

Comment: I know this may seem silly, but I'm having trouble doing the opposite - positioning the div offscreen to the left. What do I have to modify in order to achieve that, because I changed every "left" to "right," but no success.

Comment: Make it a negative left value instead of a positive one.

`hiddenDiv.style.left = '-'+docWidth+'px';`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just hide it? You can easily do it with javascript with

```
var link = document.getElementById('content');
link.style.display = 'none'; 
link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Depends on what you need it for.

Also, check this https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: I need it to be located to the right though, so that I can then use an animation to slide it in.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";   
var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.style.position = "absolute";
content.style.left = window.innerWidth + "px";
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden")
    .find("#content").css({
        "position" : "absolute",
        "left" : window.innerWidth
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9zhy2xax/